# Assets loading issue on Rails 5 app with Heroku

Tags: heroku, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

I am facing asset loading issue in Rails 5 application deployed on Heroku.

App Configuration is,

> ruby => ‘2.3.1’
>
> rails => '~> 5.0.1'

When image is stored on path,

> app/assets/home/image1.jpg

I am accessing it in view as,

```
= image_tag('/assets/home/image1.jpg’)
```

which is working properly in Development ENV, but not in Production ENV.

As per Heroku log,

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
> "/assets/home/image1.jpg")

If I am moving image directly to

> app/assets/image1.jpg

then its working on Production ENV.

Please guide about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you assets are not compile on heroku.

Follow below code:

## config/environments/production.rb

`config.assets.compile = true`
then run commands:

`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

then push all compiled files with menifest file to heroku.

Comment: Thanks. By setting config.assets.compile = true option, it works on heroku. And it works without pushing manifest file to heroku. Is it feasible to add 'public' directory to git commit code ?

Comment: @Mansi yes. Accept and vote my answer if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: What file does `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` go into?

Comment: @GMarx it creates some compressed files under public folder

Comment: better question -- @puneet18 is there a place that line of code can go in the production.rb so I don't have to run the command in terminal every time I change or add an asset?